# How to get different ranks on Pokemon-Oras?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have 30 flags on Pokemon-Oras. How am I supposed to upgrade my rank?

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate, at all. This looks like "OK I have done what that question said (the question being how much do I need, not how do I do it), what do I do to 'cash in' for a rank up.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think you have to visit the Secret Base HQ in Fortree City.